# How to override response header in jersey client

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I have a jersey client that I am trying to unmarshall a response entity with. The problem is the remote web service sends back application/octet-stream as the content type so Jersey does not know how to unmarshall it (I have similar errors with text/html coming back for XML and such). I cannot change the web service.

What I want to do is override the content-type and change it to application/json so jersey will know which marshaller to use.

I cannot register application/octet-stream with the json marshaller as for a given content type I actually might be getting back all kinds of oddities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As laz pointed out, ClientFilter is the way to go:

```
client.addFilter(new ClientFilter() {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest request) throws ClientHandlerException {
        request.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        return getNext().handle(request);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, this was almost what I wanted. Just it was the inbound response I wanted to tweak not the outbound headers. So based on your code, this works fine:

`client.addFilter(new ClientFilter() {

@Override
public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest request) throws ClientHandlerException {
    ClientResponse response = getNext().handle(request);
    response.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return response;
  }
});`

Comment: @monkjack how to do this in jersey 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well-versed in the Jersey client API, but can you use a [`ClientFilter`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/ClientFilter.html) to do this? Perhaps you could add a property to the request via [`ClientRequest.getProperties().put(String, Object)`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientRequest.html#getProperties%28%29) that tells the `ClientFilter` what `Content-Type` to override the response with. If the `ClientFilter` finds the override property, it uses it, otherwise it does not alter the response. I'm not sure if the `ClientFilter` is invoked prior to any unmarshalling though. Hopefully it is!

**Edit** (Have you tried something like this):

```
public class ContentTypeClientFilter implements ClientFilter {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest request) throws ClientHandlerException {
        final ClientResponse response = getNext().handle(request);

        // check for overridden ContentType set by other code
        final String overriddenContentType = request.getProperties().get("overridden.content.type");
        if (overriddenContentType != null) {
            response.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, overriddenContentType);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked at ClientFilter but there was no "setHeader" style method so I rejected it. If properties is the same thing then that would work. The Jersey docs seem to indicate using the filter to create a new ClientResponse but that's even more code than manually unmarshalling.

Comment: Can't you do `response.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, (String) request.getProperties().get("customer.content.type"))` or is it not possible to modify the headers in such a manner?

Answer (score 1):

Under Java 8 and Jersey 2 you can do it with a lambda:

```
client.register((ClientResponseFilter) (requestContext, responseContext) ->
                responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", "application/json"));
```