# Change what @Produces(...) produces in Jersey?

Tags: java, json, jersey, content-type

I'm new to Jersey, and would like to change what the following produces:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is ensure that the character encoding of the response is set to UTF-8. I can do this on a case by case basis if i do this on every method that produces json.

```
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

I'd of course like to do this once in my app, and have it just work everywhere. My first thought was to [implement a java filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084182/change-contenttype-or-characterencoding-in-java-filter-only-if-contenttype-j) to modify this, and I haven't been able to get that to work.

***EDIT: So to be 100% clear - I want to do this once in my app, in some global way, and have it affect all output that would be produced by Jersey for wherever I have a  `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` in my code. So if I had 100 methods that had  `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` on them, then suddenly 100 methods would now send with the content encoding UTF-8.***

So is there anyway I can just replace what `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` produces? I'd just change MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON to my new value if it wasn't final ;-)

Comment: You can use [`Response`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) to generate the response with any content type (and encoding) you want.

Comment: If all your JSON must be encoded as UTF-8 you should probably leverage the framework to __always__ do that. Depending on how you are serializing into JSON, you need to configure the serialization so that that happens. It's the most robust way.

Comment: Sure... that sounds great... so how do you think I should do that?

Comment: You can add a `ContainerResponseFilter` or a `WriterInterceptor` that do that for each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this as a `ContainerResponseFilter` that kind of overrides the behaviour of the `@Produces` annnotation in the particular case you're interested in.

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
public class MediaTypeFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        for (Annotation annotation : responseContext.getEntityAnnotations()) {
            filterProducesAnnotation(annotation, responseContext);
        }
    }

    private void filterProducesAnnotation(Annotation annotation, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        if (annotation instanceof Produces) {
            Produces produces = (Produces) annotation;
            filterMediaTypes(produces, responseContext);
        }
    }

    private void filterMediaTypes(Produces produces, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        List<Object> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (String mediaType : produces.value()) {
            contentTypes.add(mediaType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) ? mediaType + ";charset=UTF-8" : mediaType);
        }
        responseContext.getHeaders().put("Content-Type", mediaTypes);
    }
}
```

Just make sure to register the `MediaTypeFilter`with your Jersey Application.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a [default media type](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html) that has the character encoding you want.

Although an alternative to a filter could be to introduce a constant that contains your desired mimetype + character encoding. So something as simple as:

`private static final String APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8";`

The only reason for this is so that the "application/json;charset=UTF-8" isn't polluting your code as plain text (imagine refactoring if you need to change the character encoding with the 'magic string' everywhere :) )

Comment: hey... thanks for the suggestion... I'm trying to 1) make all existing code work as suggested, and 2) future proof any new code that might get introduced, that just uses the  `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` annotation, and doesn't know about the new way to do it.