# Error parsing media type '*; charset=UTF-8' when try to getType()

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mime-types, content-type

Im doing a REST call with jersey but the response media type is '*; charset=UTF-8', what throws a exception when I try response.getEntity(String.class);"

ps:. the response status is 200.

```
     ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource webResource = client
                 .resource("http://" + server);
    String inf = "username=" + user + "&target_site=" + targetSite;
    ClientResponse response = webResource.type("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, inf);
```

I simulate the same call with curl and I could see "Content-Type: *; charset=UTF-8"

Any idea what I need to do?

## UPDATE1

I tryed configure a filter like this below, but the exception still happen

```
client.addFilter(new ClientFilter() {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest request) throws ClientHandlerException {
        request.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        return getNext().handle(request);
    }
});
```

I realize that the exception happen within getType() method. It seems that the content type needed to be "*/*; charset=UTF-8", and not just "*; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override response header in jersey client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733115/how-to-override-response-header-in-jersey-client)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type '*; charset=UTF-8'
 at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:79)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:53)
 at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getType(ClientResponse.java:626)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:543)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:517).....

Comment: Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Expected separator '/' instead of ';'
 at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:121)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:90)
 at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:77)
 ... 41 more